# `read_csv` doesn't see my file in Windows

Tags: windows, pandas, filepath

I am new to using Pandas on Windows and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here.

My data is located at 'C:\Users\me\data\lending_club\loan.csv'

```
path = 'C:\\Users\\me\\data\\lending_club\\loan.csv'
pd.read_csv(path)
```

And I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-107-b5792b17a3c3> in <module>()
      1 path = 'C:\\Users\\me\\data\\lending_club\\loan.csv'
----> 2 pd.read_csv(path)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, skipfooter, skip_footer, doublequote, delim_whitespace, as_recarray, compact_ints, use_unsigned, low_memory, buffer_lines, memory_map, float_precision)
    707                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    708 
--> 709         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    710 
    711     parser_f.__name__ = name

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    447 
    448     # Create the parser.
--> 449     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    450 
    451     if chunksize or iterator:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    816             self.options['has_index_names'] = kwds['has_index_names']
    817 
--> 818         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    819 
    820     def close(self):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1047     def _make_engine(self, engine='c'):
   1048         if engine == 'c':
-> 1049             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
   1050         else:
   1051             if engine == 'python':

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1693         kwds['allow_leading_cols'] = self.index_col is not False
   1694 
-> 1695         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
   1696 
   1697         # XXX

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source()

FileNotFoundError: File b'C:\\Users\\me\\data\\lending_club\\loan.csv' does not exist
```

**EDIT:**

I re-installed Anaconda and the error went away.  Not sure exactly what was going on but could potentially have been related to the initial install being global vs. user specific in my second install.  Thanks for the help everybody!

Comment: Not sure what's wrong here. I'd just use relative paths. - Is that not a possibility?

Comment: What happens when you do `print(os.listdir(your_path))`?

Answer (score 1):

Just use forward slash(`'/'`) instead of backslash(`'\'`)

```
path = 'C:/Users/me/data/lending_club/loan.csv'
```

Answer (score 0):

Python only access to the current folder's files.
If you want to access files from an other folder, try this :

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'C:/Users/myFolder')
```

Those lines allow your script to access an other folder. Be carrefull, you shoud use slashes /, not backslashes \